# Can't access attribute 'test' on MotorClient before calling open() or open_sync()

Tags: python, pymongo, tornado-motor

I was following some [Motor examples](http://motor.readthedocs.org/en/latest/examples/gridfs.html) and they are giving me trouble. I'm using `Python2.7` in virtualenv with `tornado 3.2`, `pymongo 2.5.0` and `motor 0.1.2`. All the examples are throwing the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the "stable" version of Motor, 0.1.2, but following the "latest" examples which are built off the master branch in GitHub. Follow the "stable" examples and they'll show you how to call open_sync:

http://motor.readthedocs.org/en/stable/tutorial.html#creating-a-client

Comment: Thank you. Note to self: sleep first, then try to code.

Comment: No worries. When Motor 0.2 is released within the next couple weeks, there will be less room for confusion like this.